# Exported models not keeping UV scale from shader nodes

Tags: uv, export, .fbx

For work I frequently download new furniture and decor models from iMeshh, and they usually come with a Blender file I'll open to at least apply the transforms and re-export. They all come with a folder full of diffuse, normal and roughness maps, but when I import them into our rendering program, Lumion, it doesn't keep the correct scale on the UVs. At first I thought it was a Lumion issue, but it happens if I import that new model back into Blender, too. Every model uses the provided textures, but they all have shader node setups that alter the UV mapping. I've tried baking the maps and using the new images instead, as well as embedding the textures in an FBX export, but it still gives the same scale issues. I can resize the maps in Lumion, but then it ignores any UV mapping and makes the textures broken and patchy.

Is there some export option I'm missing, a better format, or some way to apply the UVs? Images below to show an example of the scale difference. I've been trying to figure this out off and on for a few months without much luck, partially because I'm not sure how to word it for Google search. I usually get videos and threads for different exporting issues instead.

Edit: It's not that the textures aren't exporting, that's an easy fix. It's the scale of the UV coordinates for the model itself that won't export. The models are all UV unwrapped, but use shader nodes to alter that mapping in some way that I can't figure out how to apply or export. Even if I apply all transforms and tell Blender to keep UV data on export (in the file formats that let you), the models always come into Lumion with broken UVs. This happens in FBX, DAE, and OBJ formats.

[image: Correct scale in Blender]
[image: Broken scale in Lumion]

Comment: Why not just scale the uv coordinate manually? Is it complex to setup uv mapping in shader node? If not, you can scale the uv manually according to the parameters in Mapping node. If yes, cycles can bake UV actually, but it doesn't work in your case, i think.

Comment: @IceSandwich Unfortunately, changing the texture's scale at all in Lumion completely ignores the UV mapping, so it'll show up patchy or broken. It's less of an issue for simple shapes, but very obvious on something like a pillow or bedding.